# Cipher and Decipher a File

Tags: java

I want to cipher a file, and keep the key in the file, like a ciphered text key.

Then I want to take the key from the file, and decipher the file using that key.

I have the code below,

```
public class JavaApplication8 {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, FileNotFoundException, ClassNotFoundException {
    // TODO code application logic here

    cifrarFicheiro();
    decifrarFicheiro();

}
public static void cifrarFicheiro() throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException{
    File t1 = new File("t1.txt");
    FileInputStream Fin= new FileInputStream(t1);
    byte[] texto= new byte[(int)t1.length()];
    Fin.read(texto);
    Fin.close();

    SecretKey key = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DES").generateKey();
    Cipher cifra = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
    cifra.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
    byte[] chave = key.getEncoded();
    byte[] texto_cifrado = cifra.doFinal(texto);

    FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("t1_t.txt");
    ObjectOutputStream obj = new ObjectOutputStream(fout);
    fout.write(texto_cifrado);
    obj.writeObject(chave);
    obj.close();
    fout.close();

}
public static void decifrarFicheiro() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
    FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("t1_t.txt");
    ObjectInputStream obj = new ObjectInputStream(fin);

    SecretKey chave = (javax.crypto.SecretKey)obj.readObject();
    byte []keyCifrada = chave.getEncoded();
    obj.close();

    FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("t1_chave.txt");
    ObjectOutputStream obj1 = new ObjectOutputStream(fout);
    obj1.writeObject(keyCifrada);
    byte [] text = new byte[fin.available()];
    fin.read(text);

}

}
```

But I am getting the Exception below:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: F9
      at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1377)
      at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
      at javaapplication8.JavaApplication8.decifrarFicheiro(JavaApplication8.java:59)
      at javaapplication8.JavaApplication8.main(JavaApplication8.java:31)
  Java Result: 1
```

Can anyone help me? :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all the cipher and decipher methods should be symmetric. You are calling two write operations and only reading once. If you have an ObjectOutputStream wrapping the fileoutputstream the calls should both be made on the ObjectOutputStream. StreamCorruptedException is launched when the metadata on the stream is damaged. Call the flush method to prevent that (i think). Either way you should: writeObject(texto_cifrado), writeObject(key), flush. Then read_Object(texto_cifrado), read_object(key). Acho que assim funciona lol

Answer (score -1):

public class JavaApplication8 {

```
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, FileNotFoundException, ClassNotFoundException {
    // TODO code application logic here

    cifrarFicheiro();
    decifrarFicheiro();

}
public static void cifrarFicheiro() throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException{
    File t1 = new File("t1.txt");
    FileInputStream Fin= new FileInputStream(t1);
    byte[] texto= new byte[(int)t1.length()];
    Fin.read(texto);
    Fin.close();

    SecretKey key = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DES").generateKey();
    Cipher cifra = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
    cifra.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
    byte[] chave = key.getEncoded();
    byte[] texto_cifrado = cifra.doFinal(texto);

    FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("t1_t.txt");
    ObjectOutputStream obj = new ObjectOutputStream(fout);
    obj.writeObject(texto_cifrado);
    obj.writeObject(chave);
    obj.close();
    fout.close();

}
public static void decifrarFicheiro() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException{
    FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("t1_t.txt");
    ObjectInputStream obj = new ObjectInputStream(fin);

    byte[] texto = (byte[]) obj.readObject();
    byte[] chave = (byte[]) obj.readObject();
    obj.close();

    FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("t1_chave.txt");
    ObjectOutputStream obj1 = new ObjectOutputStream(fout);
    obj1.writeObject(chave);

    FileOutputStream fout1 = new FileOutputStream("t1_texto.txt");
    ObjectOutputStream obj2 = new ObjectOutputStream(fout1);
    obj2.writeObject(texto);

    SecretKey sks = new SecretKeySpec(chave, "DES");
    Cipher c= Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
    c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE,sks);
    byte[] aux=c.doFinal(texto);

    FileOutputStream fout2 = new FileOutputStream("t1_final.txt");
    fout2.write(aux);
}
```

}

I was able to solve it. If you use Objects, you can write it in the file and the read it in the same order. In the cifrarFicheiro() function, I use the ObjectInputStream and write the text followed by the key. And then in the decifrarFicheiro() function I use de ObjectOutputStream, and I now that the first object is the text and the second is the key.

Comment: Could you explain in your answer, how you resolved the error.